# new maven POM file in eclipse java project

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-indigo, m2e

Have upgraded to eclipse.indigo using a new installation.  Added m2e.  Maven shows up under Windows>Preferences.  File>New>Other>Maven gets the following options: Checkout ..., Maven Module, Maven Project.  The Maven POM file option is missing.  I'm trying to add Maven support to an existing Java project.  Have read the manuals, searches, helps, etc.  No explanation as to why the Add POM option is missing.  Any idea how to get this option to appear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to create a POM on your project, and also change the project structure to Maven default, **right-click on your project > Configure > Convert to Maven Project**.

Don't forget to choose the correct *Packaging* type (in your case I guess it will be POM).

Answer (score 1):

I don't have this option either, seems to have disappeared with the latest version. This bug report seems to point in this direction as well:
https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-2709

The standard way should be to create a new Maven project through the wizard, which will then also contain a POM file. You could use that to create a dummy project and then copy over the POM file.

In most cases, I also just copy an existing POM file to the project and start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Quick workaround: Adding a POM by hand. (Also I'm not sure that I've ever seen an "Add POM" option.)

Simply add a file to your project (New > General > File), and name it *pom.xml*. On double-click on this file, the POM Editor will open.